# To calculate total booking made and total amount collected using sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to display the resort id, resort name, the count of booking made in each resort, and the total amount collected in each resort. For that I have a piece of code as follows;

```
select r.resortid, r.resortname, count(b.bookingid) as totalbooking, sum(b.totalcharge) as totalamount
 from resort r inner join booking b 
 on r.resortid = b.resortid  
 group by b.resortid
 order by b.resortid;
```

But this code gives an error stating "Not a group by expression". Please help through this, and thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add in the additional unaggregated columns:

```
select r.resortid, r.resortname,
       count(b.bookingid) as totalbooking, 
       sum(b.totalcharge) as totalamount
from resort r inner join
     booking b 
     on r.resortid = b.resortid  
group by r.resortid, r.resortname
order by r.resortid;
```

Note that the `group by` columns match the unaggregated columns in the `select`.  In particular, the `group by`  and `order by` use `r.resortid`, not `b.resortid`.

You could also use aggregation functions:

```
select r.resortid, max(r.resortname) as resortname,
       count(b.bookingid) as totalbooking, 
       sum(b.totalcharge) as totalamount
from resort r inner join
     booking b 
     on r.resortid = b.resortid  
group by r.resortid
order by r.resortid;
```